# Updating kubernetes helm values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I'd like to update a value config for a helm release on my cluster.

Something like

`helm update -f new_values.yml nginx-controller`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
helm upgrade -f ingress-controller/values.yml nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress
```

Or more generally:

```
helm upgrade -f new-values.yml {release name} {package name or path} --version {fixed-version}
```

The command above does the job.

Unless you manually specify the version with the `--version {fixed-version}` argument, `upgrade` will also update the chart version. You can find the current chart version with `helm ls`.

Docs: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

Comment: Can you include new keys in the `new-values.yml` file that aren't in the original chart?  I'm trying to add a pod `antiAffinity` block to pods in an existing (not mine) chart.

Comment: `➜  helm list -A
NAME                   NAMESPACE REVISION UPDATED                              STATUS   CHART                       APP VERSION
my-prometheus-operator default   1        2020-07-07 20:31:28.019196 +0530 IST deployed prometheus-operator-8.15.11 0.38.1
vvp                    vvp       1        2020-07-08 14:30:30.330573 +0530 IST deployed ververica-platform-4.1.1    2.1.1
➜  helm upgrade -f values-min.yaml vvp  ververica-platform-4.1.1
Error: failed to download "ververica-platform-4.1.1" (hint: running helm repo update may help)`
Still I am not able to upgrade

Comment: Note that in case of updating values of the nginx ingress controller and if one has additional configuration options specified via the ConfigMap, the content of the ConfigMap will get emptied when doing a `helm upgrade`. Recreate the ConfigMap afterwards.

Answer (score 22):

This is how I update the current chart with new values, without upgrading the chart version:

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values -f values.yaml {release-name} {release-path} --version {fixed-version}
```

For example:

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values -f prometheus/values.yaml prometheus-operator stable/prometheus-operator --version 5.7.0 --namespace monitoring
```

I use a fixed version of the installed chart, and add --reuse-values flag to ensure that I keep the previous values I used.

Comment: thanks! it didn't trigger the new deployment so pod stayed with same values

Answer (score 21):

**EDIT 2020-04-03:**

`--recreate-pods --wait` is not recommended anymore. As Jorden pointed out one way is to add a checksum annotations that will implies to restart the pods if any file change. see https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments for reference doing so.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

To complement the answer of @stan-bondi, you can do :

```
helm upgrade --recreate-pods --wait -f new_values.yaml nginx-controller nginx-controller
```

This is often needed when you juste changed a configMap or secrets that wont be detected as a change in the release itself.

Comment: About --recreate-pods, it seems this is no longer recommended.  See here for an alternative: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: Totally true @JørgenTvedt this answer was designed for helm 2 and it a bit outdated. I will update it.

Comment: @webofmars How's that done (concerning your edit)
I installed the chart with helm install. But I just cannot figure out how to change the deployment in the way it is described at the link you provided. Could you please elaborate on that? Thank you

Comment: @AndyB You can just copy paste the given exemple:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```
Just point the exemple of configmap.yaml to something that is likely to change at each deployment :-)

Comment: @webofmars
Thank you. But question is: where: I am completely new to helm, if I just do an install, I don't have access to the deployment.yaml? At least I did not find out how, after hours of searching. The answer is probably totally easy, but I might oversee something here.
It's a chart from the bitnami team, which I used directly. We need a zero downtime solution

Comment: @AndyB I would consider to open a PR on the public chart offered by bitnani. Also many charts offers to surcharge the annotations of the deployments so i guess you can do that in a local copy of the values.yaml you pass to -f

Answer (score 3):

I just changed install to upgrade and that worked for me.

```
helm upgrade \
  airflow \
  airflow-stable/airflow \
  --version 7.16.0 \
  --namespace airflow \
  --values airflow.config.yaml
```

If it's still giving you trouble after this, you can recycle all the pods in the namespace like so

```sh
kubectl delete pods -n airflow --all
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `Deployment`(or `StatefulSet`) yaml file, and if you are using `ConfigMap` or `Secret` you can add a checksum like below:

```
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config-env: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap-env.yaml") . | sha256sum }}

...
```

This will detect a changed in the configMap that wont be detected as a change in the release itself.

Comment: Dumb question, but do I edit the yaml within K8s dashboard or locally and then apply it with kubectl or helm? Or something else?

Comment: Locally and then kubectl apply

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

> helm upgrade -f new_values.yaml nginx-controller nginx-controller

This will update the revision of your chart which can be viewed using:

> helm ls

or more specifically:

> helm get nginx-controller

For helm chart upgrades, check this link from the docs: https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-upgrade

Comment: Ah ha, so maybe can update the answer - my problem was in all the examples for helm they use `helm upgrade -f ingress-controller/helm-values.yml nginx-ingress ./some/path` but you can use remote helm package name in the last argument like so `helm upgrade -f ingress-controller/helm-values.yml nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress` and that will upgrade to the latest chart too. 

What if I just want to update the values and have helm recompile the templates and apply them?