# Updating helmfile state in the cluster without a helmfile apply

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile, argo-rollouts, kubernetes-java-client

is there a way to directly edit the helm state in a cluster without a helmfile apply?

We're in a situation where we need to update resources (argo rollouts) managed by helmfile from outside, i.e., using either the Java APIs or directly editing them on k9s.
We have our helmfile configs pushed up on github, but simply updating these values to match the values changed via the Java API or k9s still results in a diff (which I don't want)

Comment: You can `helm upgrade` with just the new values as in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927233/updating-kubernetes-helm-values), would that work for you?

Comment: Helmfile fundamentally wraps Helm, so if you run individual `helm upgrade` commands, those will in effect also update the Helmfile state.  But if you make manual changes with commands like `kubectl edit`, that will confuse Helm and with it Helmfile.